# JavaFX Use one Loader load two different nodes

Tags: javafx

Everyone.I would like to ask, Can we use one loader to load two different FXMLs at one time? Actually, I want to know whether can I load two fxmls, so that these two fxmls can be displayed at the same time, at one screen.

```
    public class NodeLink extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)loader.load(getClass().getResource("StartPanel.fxml"));
    Group centralNode = (Group)loader.load(this.getClass().getResource("CentralNode.fxm."));
    root.getChildren().setAll(centralNode);
    //Group centralNode = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CentralNode.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

As above, Group centralNode = ... this statement will cause error, as follows:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)...
```

So, why this will cause errors? Can we use several fxmls once to make up a screen?
Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't actually use the `FXMLLoader` you created at all here: the method `load(URL)` that you invoke (twice) is a static method. But you say "something is wrong". Can you explain what goes wrong?

Comment: Just posting a snippet of the stack trace is not really going to help. What root causes of the exception are listed and what lines of your code do they come from?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and advice. I've already try to express it more clearer. If anyone still can't not understand what I want to say, please let me konw, I will try to do it better. Thank you so much , James_D.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: I assume the "CentralNode.fxm." is just a typo from copying from your code to the question, right?

Comment: Hi, James_D. I feel ashamed that I just type "fxm." and after I change it, everything seems OK. Shame on me. Thank you so much for your time.I  appreciate it. I will be more careful next time.